# How to disable subdomain in apache2?

Tags: apache-2.2

I've enabled the 'www' subdomain host record that points to mysite.com on my domain registrar's DNS editor a few days ago and the changes have propagated.

However I would like to temporarily disable it.

1) Why does www.mysite.com work even though I've commented out the following code in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite`?

```
#<VirtualHost *:80>
#ServerAlias www.mysite.com
#DocumentRoot /mywebsite
#</VirtualHost>
```

Is it even needed to make changes in apache2 to enable the subdomain?

2) How can I temporarily disable the 'www' subdomain from apache2?

Comment: Not knowing the rest of the contents in the apache config file, it's a little hard to answer :)

Comment: I am not entirely sure what the effect of only specifying "ServerAlias" and not "ServerName", maybe its gets caught by another virtualhost section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to start by restarting apache to force reloading the apache config, to ensure its using the most recent directives;

`service httpd restart`  <-- on centos or redhat
`/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`  <--- on debian or ubuntu

If this is a live production site, you might also want to consider running a configuration check before applying the changes;

`service httpd configtest`  <-- on centos or redhat
`Syntax OK`
`/etc/init.d/apache2 configtest`  <--- on debian or ubuntu

if apache does not recognise the alias `www.mysite.com` then it will get sent to the default site, either _default_:80 or *:80, depending on whether you have configured `NameVirtualHost *:80`

if you are on a sensible OS, then the `apachectl` command can be used to enumerate the virtualHosts that apache knows about like so;

```
[root@g0803 init.d]# apachectl -S
VirtualHost configuration:
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80          is a NameVirtualHost  
default server g0801.hpl.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/boopo.conf:110)        
port 80 namevhost 01.hpl.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/boopo.conf:110)     
     port 80 namevhost portal.boep.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/lime-portal.conf:5)   
_default_:443          g0803.hpl.com (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:81)
Syntax OK
```

With HTTP 1.1 and name based virtual hosting, apache inspects the "Host" header in order to decide where to send the request, so unless you wish to switch the subdomain record over to some null destination, you are going to need to put in a VirtualHost to catch these requests with the www Host header, and redirect them to either a holding page, or to some dead end server.

A temporary work-around is to point your site to some empty folder, or back to the default home page e.g;

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAlias www.mysite.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, I'm using the temporary work around until the dns changes propagate.  It seems if I comment out your work around, the default behavior is to set the www.mysite.com alias to the document root of /mywebsite like you mentioned.